# MavensMate Slow Compile Times

Tags: apex, visualforce, mavensmate

I've recently started using MavensMate, joining quite a large existing project. When working with a developer edition org, compilation times with mavensmate were fast and there was no issues. However with the larger project I'm seeing some extortionate compile times for both apex classes and visualforce pages, in the region of 2-3mins. Sometimes the process appears to just hang, and I have to close it and try again. I've tried enabling/disabling the tooling api in project settings to no avail. Does anyone have any idea what may be causing the issue?

Edit:
Even refreshing a file from the Salesforce server seems to exhibit the same behaviour. Refreshing metadata container works fine. May have to switch to Eclipse until I can find a solution to this.

Comment: I've had the same issue.

Comment: Hi, have you find out a solution for your issue? Thanks

Comment: Try turning the api tooling on or off, whatever the opposite of what you have is

Comment: This is quite an old question now. I never really found a solve, it just seems to be an intermittent issue. Also I did try the tooling api enable/disable, as I said in the original question.

Answer (score 2):

Under the Mavensmate dropdown list select Utilities > Refresh Metadata Container. That usually fixes it for me.

Comment: This didn't solve the issue for me.